# Can not execute python script or go to python shell

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I can not run my Python script or even run command Python to go to python shell. What's wrong with my Python?

```
machine:project user$ python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 62, in <module>
    import os
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 398, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
  File "abc.py", line 2, in <module>
    import scipy.special
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 5, in <module>
    import collections
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 6, in <module>
    __all__ += _abcoll.__all__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'
```

But anyway everything still looks fine if run Python outside my project directory.

Comment: do `ls` in your project directory, likely you're shadowing an internal module with one of your own since current working directory is the first directory looked at in the python path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a local file called `abc.py` which is hiding the built-in `abc` module. Rename your file to something else.