# Python unable to start

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to run Python 2.7 from terminal, but it is not opening the python shell. Instead it gives an attribute error. The screen shot is attached below[image]

What is the error? The python IDE's are working fine.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479999/can-not-execute-python-script-or-go-to-python-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a local file that is shadowing the abc system library. When python starts, it is loading `/home/hduser/abc.py` instead of the system library `abc`. Remove or rename that file and you should be good!