# AttributeError while starting the python interpreter

Tags: python

The python interpreter throws the following error and exits while starting.

```
:~$ python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 68, in <module>
    import os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 400, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 116, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
  File "abc.py", line 2, in <module>
    import logging
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, cStringIO, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py", line 18, in <module>
    __all__ += _abcoll.__all__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'
```

I am sure that it is pointing to correct `python` binary.

```
:~$ ls -la `which python`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Sep  9  2016 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

I have tried to reinstall the `python2.7`, but wasn't helpful.

```
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install python2.7 python-pip python-dev
```

Comment: Since when has this problem been occurring for you? What did you do to trigger it?

Comment: It is resolved now.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479999/can-not-execute-python-script-or-go-to-python-shell